# Provide NextFlow workflow inputs (not parameters) via the CLI

Tags: nextflow

I have the following (simplified) nextflow module. It has one process, which runs a multiple sequence alignment on a fasta file, and a workflow that runs this process (eventually it will run other processes too):

```
process clustal_omega_msa {
    input:
      path fastas
    output:
      path 'clustal.sto'
    script:
      """
      cat ${fastas} > merged.fa
      clustalo -infile merged.fa --outfmt=stockholm
      """
    container "https://depot.galaxyproject.org/singularity/clustalo:1.2.4--h1b792b2_4"
}

workflow msa {
  take:
    path fastas
  main:
    clustal_omega_msa(fastas)
}
```

I want this workflow to be both importable as a sub-workflow, and also executable directly. For this reason I have specified no parameters, and only used inputs (because I believe parameters can't be specified when calling a subworkflow).

However, I can see no way to run this subworkflow directly on the command line.

If I run `nextflow run msa.nf -entry msa` I get the following error:

```
No such variable: fastas

 -- Check script 'msa.nf' at line: 1 or see '.nextflow.log' file for more details
```

This makes sense - I haven't specified where these files come from. But how can I? If I follow the [config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html) part of the docs and create a `nextflow.config` with the following contents:

```
fastas = "/some/path/to/*.fasta"
```

I still get this error. I am also aware there is a `-params-file` option, but I believe that only works for parameters, not inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implicit workflow definitions](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#implicit-workflow) are ignored when a script is imported as module. This means that your workflow script that can be used either as a library module or as an application script:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2
params.input_fasta_files = './data/*.fasta'


process clustal_omega_msa {

    input:
    path fastas
    
    output:
    path 'clustal.sto'

    """
    cat ${fastas} > merged.fa
    clustalo -infile merged.fa --outfmt=stockholm
    """
}

workflow msa {
  
    take:
    fasta_files
  
    main:
    clustal_omega_msa(fasta_files)
}

workflow {

    input_fasta_files = Channel.fromPath( params.input_fasta_files ).collect()

    msa( input_fasta_files )
}
```

Note that if you were to move the 'msa' sub-workflow into a separate file, for example called 'msa.nf', you could then just import it and specify any required params to it using the [addParams option](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-parameters). For example:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

include { msa } from './path/to/msa.nf' addParams(foo: 'bar')

params.input_fasta_files = './data/*.fasta'


workflow {

    input_fasta_files = Channel.fromPath( params.input_fasta_files ).collect()

    msa(input_fasta_files)
}
```

Comment: Both excellent suggestions, thank you. It seems that both of these are methods of adding parameters to the subworkflow rather than actually specifying the inputs on the CLI? I suppose my original problem isn't possible then?

Comment: No worries at all @Migwell. So I'm not sure if I have understood correctly. If you were to specify `--input_fasta_files '/path/to/*.fasta'` on the command-line, then this would override the existing value for `params.input_fasta_files` specified in the script, which would override any value specified in your nextflow.confg or other config files. Please see: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/getstarted.html#pipeline-parameters

Comment: Also, have a look at the [params scope](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-params) for how to specify params in your nextflow.config. In your example, for example, you'd need `params.fastas = "/some/path/to/*.fasta"`. HTH.

Comment: So you have shown me how to use *parameters*, I was just wanting to know if I can specify workflow inputs from the CLI without using parameters. Possibly you can't, I just wanted to make sure though

Comment: I think params are still the right way to go to make your input channels. Workflow inputs must be channels (or a simple data type, which will create a value channel). This is what the note at the bottom of this section says anyway: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#workflow-inputs HTH